# cropToContents not working properly in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I have a template qpt which I read via pyqgis script to export multiple maps as png. I have a map and a legend in qpt file and I chose "Only show items inside linked map" so the legend shows the items only in the map. While exporting images, I would like to crop to content so that I do not have extra empty white space. Therefore, I am using `image_export_settings.cropToContents = True`. However, it seems not working. This is how my map looks when I export
[image]

And if I used `image_export_settings.cropToContents = True`, it looks like. It just crops the legend as well.
[image]
Part of my code looks like this

```
# Read the layout temp
templateFile = open(xxx_qpt, 'r')
templateContent = templateFile.read()
templateFile.close()

doc = QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(templateContent)

layout = QgsLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.page(0).setPageSize('A4', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Portrait )

items, ok = layout.loadFromTemplate(doc, QgsReadWriteContext(), False)

# Adjust frame
mapFrame = layout.itemById("Map1")
mapFrame.zoomToExtent(bbox[0])

# Get the scale of  Layout
referencemap = layout.referenceMap()

wmts_scale = [
    1126,
    2252,
    4504,
    9008,
    18016,
    ]

layer_extent_scale = referencemap.scale()
closest_scale = min(wmts_scale, key=lambda x:abs(x-layer_extent_scale))

index = wmts_scale.index(closest_scale)    
mapFrame.setScale(wmts_scale[index+3])

# Export an image of the layout object
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
image_export_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
image_export_settings.cropToContents = True
exporter.exportToImage(imgDir + f"\{str(id)}.jpg", image_export_settings)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try using the same extent while importing manually and with a script. Is the result the same?

Comment: It works manually as I expected -cropped correctly

Comment: Try to remove any extra code not related to the image export function.

Comment: @ComradeChe after `# Get the scale of  Layout` until image export?

Comment: The goal is to keep the code as clean as possible in order to understand what is causing this problem. Remove almost everything except  `exporter.exportToImage`, and check the result. If it meets expectations - add new lines of code so that you can understand what causes the unwanted result.

Comment: You may play with margins parameter because used together with `cropToContents` in QGIS unit tests e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayoutexporter.py#L359

Comment: Did you try in different versions of QGIS? It works as expected in QGIS 3.16.0 Hannover in my pc.

Comment: Hmmm. No, I tried only with 3.10.12. I will try it with other version.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz it did not work. I tried with QGIS 3.12 & 3.16 Do you think my qpt has some problem that it causes this?

Comment: I've no idea. I have not worked on qpt file so far. Just used to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly a QGIS based answer and more a workaround, but if the usage of an additional tool like [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org) is an option, you could use the [trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim.) switch/ command.

```bsh
$ convert -trim input.png output.png
```

You could call it directly from your python code `os.system(command)` or use the python bindings [pythonmagick](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonMagick) to implement the program feature. Something like:

```py
import PythonMagick
image = PythonMagick.Image("input.png")
image.trim()
image.write("output.png")
```